# How to copy structure of database in another database in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a database and want to copy all the tables in new database without copying the dat of all those tables only structure should be copy

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Management Studio offers the following:

Scripting the whole database:

- Under the Object Explorer, right mouse click on the database and then select `Script Database as`

To script just (specific) tables:

- In Object Explorer, right mouse click on the database, select `Tasks`, then `Generate Scripts`, and then select the tables that you want.

You can then use the script to create a new database / new objects elsewhere. If you change  the name of the database, remember to change the `USE xxx` statement(s) accordingly.

Comment: Any advice on what to do if a lot of the tables fail during this process?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS for your first database right click on the datbaase name then "Script Database as" > "CREATE To" then choose your output location and run your script.

Edit:

Note you will need to amend the script to specify the new database name, replacing the existing one in the generated script (courtesy of Oded comment).

Comment: Though you would need to specify the new database name, replacing the existing one in the generated script...

Comment: The user wants to copy table structures as well.  This does not do that.  (Does it?)

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL server Management Studio you can right click the database -> tasks -> export data. Then follow the wizard..